# Doubts with laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I make this schema to save the prices in a specific season in a specific board

Example: Hotel X half board octuber 50€ , full board 50€ ...

```
    Schema::create('boards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 45);
    });

    Schema::create('seasons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 45);
    });

    Schema::create('hotels', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 45);
        $table->string('city');
        $table->unsignedInteger('agency_id');

        $table->foreign('agency_id')->references('id')->on('agencies');

        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('hotel_schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('hotel_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('board_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('season_id');
        $table->decimal('price', 7, 2);

        $table->foreign('hotel_id')->references('id')->on('hotels');
        $table->foreign('board_id')->references('id')->on('boards');
        $table->foreign('season_id')->references('id')->on('seasons');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

What is the correct way to add relationship between the models Boards, Seasons and Hotels?
Is correct to create another model call HotelSchedule?

Thanks

Comment: I think its right to create that intermediate table `hotel_schedules` for that's where the tables are related.

Answer (score 0):

Boards and schedule has a many to many relationship, so you typically should have a pivot table board_schedule and a corresponding model  BoardSchedule, from your explanation above it seems like  a board can have multiple schedules and a schedule can have many boards.

Board season is a one to many relationship, A board can only have one season, but a season can belong to many boards,seasons hotel is many to many because a season can have multiple hotels and an hotel can belong to many seasons.
On your BoardSchedule model you should have something like this

```
public function Schedule(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Schedule')
        ->withPivot('hotel_schedule', 'board_id');
}

public function Board(){
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Board')
    ->withPivot('hotel_board', 'schedule_id');
}
```

A Schedule can also have many hotels and an hotel can belong to multiple schedules , so just like above it's many to many again on your HotelSchedule model

```
public function Schedule(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Schedule')
        ->withPivot('hotel_schedule', 'hotel_id');

}
public function Hotel(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Schedule')
       ->withPivot('hotel_schedule', 'schedule_id');
}
```

Hope this helps.